# How can we encourage users to accept correct answers?

Tags: discusión

I have been reading the meta a little bit, and there are some questions about encouraging people to ask more questions, doing more voting-up for good questions, and the like.

I was wondering how can we encourage users to accept answers for their questions. The numbers (statistics) for the site look amazing. Questions are answered quickly, often get more than one answer and usually really well explained (I can tell that there's some users here that are real pros), but many of those questions don't have an accepted answer.

I think that accepting the answers (and voting up, of course) helps to show that users **do** find a quality answer for their questions, that they are happy with their experience on this site and that this stack is useful and a valuable tool. I'm also positive that it would be very good for the community and could help us to move further on getting beyond the *beta* phase.

How can we encourage users to accept what they think is the besta answer to each of their questions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good way.  There are a lot of fly-by question asking.  People will ask the question, then probably lose their log-in information and not come back to the site.  We could try to have a non-question-answerer suggest in a comment that they accept an answer (so as not to appear too biased), but if they don't log back on....